# How to get time and date in this format: Mar 26 '19?

Tags: javascript

How can I get this type of date format: `mm dd 'yy`, e.g. Mar 26 '19,  in JavaScript?

Comment: some libraries, you'd use `mmm d ''yy` - but, natively use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

Comment: can you tell me the library please?

Comment: Well which library are you using? If none so far, have you looked into date formatting libraries for JS?

Comment: date_fns - but I didn't say that

Answer (score 2):

You can use the methods from a `Date` instance, format the outputs and join them into an only string.

```js
const date = new Date();
const month = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' }).substr(0, 3);
const day = date.getDate();
const year = date.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2);

const formattedDate = `${month} ${day} '${year}`;

console.log(formattedDate);
```